# Decision trees visualization

Tags: java, javascript, r, decision-tree

Does anyone know a free framework for visualizing decision trees that allows the use of events (double-click a node for additional split)? I am interested in using these events to trigger additional calculations in R/Python/other.

Background on my request: I need to be able to efficiently incorporate business rules with a optimized splits (through the usual algorithms) into a single tree.

I know there are proprietary tools for this dynamic tree building (SAS,FICO,Angoss,etc) but I need a free visualization framework to pair up with an existing solution.

I tried adapting [google's visualization API for organizational charts](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#org_chart), but it does not fully support the events I had in mind; and also calling R from Javascript seems a bit of a rocky road.

MANY THANKS FOR ANY FEEDBACK!!!

Comment: What is the need of Java and Javascript in your project?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what events the google framework does not support, it does support collapsing trees. You can also call the api from within R with `googleVis` package

Comment: I added Java and Javascript as I thought they could provide be the building blocks for a solution... maybe it was wishful thinking.

Comment: Thanks Seth, I am now looking into GoogleVis. My current problem with the Google framework is not being able to fire an R script/function from a click on a node. Maybe a simplest example of what I am trying to achieve is: when I click on a node I want R to create a new child node using a defined script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have been able to dig there are 2 tools that might work as the framework for me to build the GUI I need:

http://www.graphviz.org/ and http://processing.org/

If you have any other options please post them!!!